# Crystal Report Server - Print Job Limit

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

May be this question considered as bored. So i need suggestions for improving question as well.
As you all know that Crystal Report Developer edition for Visual Studio (free) has job limit equal to 75. Our clients are using crystal reports so excessively that we are encountering this error

> The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached."

I have found multiple solutions for it and i has tried mostly  all of them.

- Disposed off Report document object
- Incremented the Print Job Limit value in registry
- Decreasing the Recycle Time of Application Pool time in IIS.

but still this issue is happening after some time. So we decided to go for **Crystal Report Server 2016** to purchase 5 concurrent Access Package.
So my question, actually questions are:

- How Crystal Report Server will overcome this printing Job limit error?
- We have multiple .Net web applications which are using crystal reports. So Crystal Report Server will allow all our End users to print crystal reports through our web applications?

Answer (score 2):

Recently I have encountered this issue too,
there are some tips for registry:
First you need to increment the limit value in registry by this command :

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\10.2\Report Application Server\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 9999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\9.0\Report App\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer"  /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 9999 /f
```

After that you need to restart the server which you work on it.
But if you using 64 bit servers and that not worked for you, You have to register it in wo6432node too:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\10.2\Report Application Server\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 9999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\9.0\Report App\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer"  /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 9999 /f

REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Crystal Decisions\10.2\Report Application Server\InProcServer"  /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Crystal Decisions\10.2\Report Application Server\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Crystal Decisions\9.0\Report App\InprocServer"  /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Crystal Decisions\9.0\Report App\Server"  /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\InprocServer"  /v  PrintJobLimit /d 99999 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Report Application Server\Server" /v  PrintJobLimit /d 9999 /f

@echo off

pause
```

at the end again you need to restart it again.
Hope it's work for your first issue.